# Android studio emulator problem

Tags: android

When I try to start my emulator I receive the following:

```
20:09   adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (39); killing...

20:09   could not read ok from ADB Server

20:09   * failed to start daemon

20:09   error: cannot connect to daemon

20:09   'C:\Users\10349\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

What was the problem? and how may I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the code you are using to open the emulator?

Comment: I open it straight from android studio, this little green icon on the top right

Comment: Perhaps it's referring to Appium server?  If you have the desktop version, launch it manually, then try to launch your emulator.

Comment: I have try to follow the path to open it manually, but its being terminated once I launch it

Comment: Did you install it using NodeJS? `npm install -g appium`

Comment: It was a built-in function in android studio

Comment: Check out : https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/20524/how-to-resolve-adb-server-version-32-doesnt-match-this-client-36-killin

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your android SDK installed within android studio to match the client device version.

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update